# How to make and if else / conditional division in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to make a condition in CakePHP?

In WordPress I can only make it using

```
<?php if(is_page('1')){ ?>

 <section id="flash-area">
       <div class="flash oswald">
          .....................
        </div>      
   </section>
<?php }else {?>
    //i will removed this div

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Wordpress and CakePHP are both build with PHP you can just use plain PHP for this. In your Template file (e.g. *src/Template/Pages/home.ctp*) do:

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    <section id="flash-area">
        <div class="flash oswald">
            .....................
        </div>
    </section>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div>Another div</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You can also use [alternative control structures](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#alternative-control-structures) for cleaner code:

```
<?php if ($condition): ?>
    <section id="flash-area">
        <div class="flash oswald">
            .....................
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Since you didn't wrote, which condition you want to test, I assume you want to check if you're on a specific (static) page of the PagesController. Your Condition would just look like:

```
<?php if ($page == 'home'): ?>
```

You can set the conditional variables in a Controller.

Comment: i forgot to mention I want to do this in login.ctp only and the division to removed or replace is in the default.ctp.  I tried to put $page = 'login'  in login method userscontroller and put this one default.ctp nothing happen  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7988704f13c91a7187f841a68d49c253

Comment: Please be more precise in what you want to do. The $page variable is only available View rendered by the PagesController. If you simply want to add a [Flash Message](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html), if your login() method is called, then add `$this->Flash->set('This is a message');` in your login method. You could also set a variable in your Controller, which can be accessed in the View like: `$this->set('condition', true);`

Comment: nope I want to removed some area when im in login.ctp .. the code I want to removed in in default.ctp which has the code above

Comment: In your login() do `$this->set('hideFlash', true);`, in your .ctp do `<?php if (!$hideFlash): ?>
    <section id="flash-area">
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: awesome :) how it happen? can you explain more bro

Comment: You have to [set View variables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views), which can be accessed in your View. Try to stick to the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html) and learn about [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)